# wp_update_user is not updating if user id is not hard coded

Tags: wordpress, frontend, profile, custom-fields

Trying to update user table through following code :

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_id= (int)($user->ID);

    // only update the user in if there are no errors
    if(empty($errors)) {
        $user_data=wp_update_user( array( 'ID'=>$user_id,
                'display_name'      =>$display_name,
                'user_email'        => $user_email));
}
```

And if I simply hard code user ID then it is updating. What is wrong in the code while current user id is saving in the variable and printing on the page...

Comment: Same problem - any solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $user = wp_get_current_user();

 $user_id= $user->ID;

 $display_name= 'xxx';

 $user_email= 'email'; 

if(empty($errors)) {
    $user_data=wp_update_user( array( 'ID'=>$user_id,
            'display_name'      =>$display_name,
            'user_email'        => $user_email));
}
```

try as such your  code

Comment: My code is updating perfectly iff I pass ID=>2 or any number
But if I try to pass $user->ID or $user_Id it doesn't update